# TImageList 32bit icons with multiple images looks bad?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, timagelist

I'm new to C++ Builder. I just added my normal icons to a `TImageList` that is set to 32bit, and it looks bad (when looking in the `TImageList` via IDE or in the Control it's used, like a `TTreeView`).  The icons have multiple sizes, one such has 48x48, 32x32, 24x24, 16x16, all RGB/A.  The 32x32 `TImageList` looks a little better than the 16x16 `TImageList`, it's almost like it added the first size found 48x48 and scaled it down instead of picking the size that matches the `TImageList`, but that would be a major limitation and not make any sense.  I must be doing something wrong?   Is there a solution to ensure they look good?

---

**EDIT:**

I did a test by removing all items from the 16x16 `TImageList` and added this (after adding a `.rc` file to the project, of course):

```cpp
void __fastcall TSharedDataModule::DataModuleCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
     for (UINT i=IDI_USER_ICON_START; i<=IDI_USER_ICON_END; i++) {
         TIcon *icon = new TIcon;
         icon->Handle = reinterpret_cast<HICON>(LoadImageW(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i), IMAGE_ICON, ImageList16->Width, ImageList16->Height, 0));
         ImageList16->AddIcon(icon);
         delete icon;
    }
}
```

And the icons look great in the `TTreeView`, so it does look like a bug or missing feature in the IDE to load the correct image from `.ico` files.

I did notice my `TDBGrid` icons are now pure black, so I'll have to deal with that next.

Is that the answer, or am I missing something I need to do in the IDE?

Comment: Define "looks bad". How about some screenshots? Also, for multi-resolution images, consider using `TVirtualImageList` with `TImageCollection`, see [Supporting high-DPI images with the Image Collection and Virtual ImageList components](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Supporting_high-DPI_images_with_the_Image_Collection_and_Virtual_ImageList_components).

Comment: I looked at TImageCollection but it doesn't support .ico files.

Comment: I added additional item to question.

Comment: `TImageCollection` stores [`TWICImage`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TWICImage) objects, and WIC supports ICO images. But even if it didn't, you can assign a `TIcon` to a `TBitmap` and then add the BMP image to the collection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess your saying since the IDE `TImageCollection` wouldn't take .ico files and I now have to load in code anyway, I can load .ico files to a `TImageCollection` in code.  Would I need to link them after loading or can leave linked and just load the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the statement in Delphi documentation, TImageList cannot handle 32bit semi-transparent images at design-time.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Controls.TImageList

PNG or BMP (32-bit, premultiplied or not) - will produce the bug. Following is an example of three images (non-premultiplied bmp, premultiplied bmp, png) on different backgrounds:

[On clBtnFace background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJcBc.png)

[On clGreen background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0abqw.png)

It's a long lasting bug. It exists in all Delphi versions including the latest Delphi 11.